# unique key on two columns commutatively

Tags: sql-server

please suggest me how to apply unique key on two columns comparatively. i.e. suppose we have two columns FK_Col1 and FK_Col2 and if we insert 2 and 6 in both columns then  we should not be able to insert again 2 and 6 or 6 and 2 in both columns.

Plaese suggest me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: make it uniquie key

Comment: ALTER TABLE TestTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT uq_FK_Col1_FK_Col2  UNIQUE(column1, column2);

Comment: A composite primary key, unique constraint, or unique index will ensure no more than one row can have the same values.

Comment: @DanGuzman But it's not just a composite key required, the difference is that the order of columns is not important here.

Comment: @DavidG, you are right. I saw that after I made my comment but it was too late to delete it.

Comment: using unique key on both columns doesn't solve my problem as if we insert (2, 6) in both columns then we are not able to insert (2, 6) again  but we can insert (6, 2).
Please suggest me how to get this kind of constraint on two columns.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a calculated column and a unique constraint on it. The trick is that we want the calculated column to have the same value for both `(2),(6)` and for `(6),(2)`:

```
create table #t (a int, b int,
    uq_col as (case when a>b then cast(a as varchar)+'|'+cast(b as varchar) else cast(b as varchar)+'|'+cast(a as varchar) end),
    constraint uq_t__a_b unique(uq_col))
```

Answer (score 0):

WHILE  creating table

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  COLUMN1 INT NOT NULL,
  COLUMN2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT unique_1 UNIQUE (column1, column2)
)
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT unique_1 UNIQUE(column1, column2)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (now I've taken a proper look at it) as the order of the columns is not important in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, though this doesn't solve my problem, as I want unique key constraint commutatively that means if we once insert (2, 6) in (FK_Key1, FK_Key2) respectively then  we should not be able to insert (2, 6) or (6, 2) in both columns.